# Web API Post Method frombody is null

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have Post Method

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(MemberViewModel model)
```

Another Post Method in same Controller. I add the attribute routing in login method

```
[Route("api/members/login")]
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Login([FromBody]LoginViewModel model)
{}

public class LoginViewModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

The default post method is working fine but 
when I call Login Post Method the model (LoginViewModel is always null). I used fiddler to do the testing.

**Fiddler**

POST http://localhost:49595/api/members/login/         Http/1.1

User-Agent: Fiddler

Content-Type: Application/JSON

Host: localhost:49595

Content-Length: 79

Request Body
{
    “Username”: customer@gmail.com,
    “Password”: “393f83x393”
}

It is working fine with one parameter

```
[Route("api/members/login")]
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Login([FromBody]string userName)
{}
```

Kindly advice what wrong with Model

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your Fiddler shows this line:

> Request Body { “Username”: customer@gmail.com, “Password”: “393f83x393” }

That's not valid JSON. The email account should be enclosed in single or double quotes.

Comment: Hi JotaBe, thanks for your answer. Actually, I forget to enclosed double quotes for Username in my question. I think Fiddler has some issue.